# Update Route Model from Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, youtube, frameworks, components

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to create an application that mimics Youtube by using their API. Currently I have a route that is responsible for grabbing the initial information from the Youtube Api to populate the page on load. I have a search bar component that is used to gather the input from the user and repopulate the list with results based on the string. The problem is that while I am getting the input from the user my Route model is not refreshing to grab the update data from the api. Below is my code.

Template for my video route video.hbs:

```
// app/templates/video.hbs
<div class="row">
  {{search-bar}}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <hr>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      {{video-list model=model}}
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right video-container">
          {{#if  videoId}}
            <iframe id="video-player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoId}}"></iframe>
          {{else}}
            <iframe id="video-player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kEpOF7vUymc"></iframe>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Template for my search bar

```
// app/templates/components/search-bar.hbs
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-4">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false">
        {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=search id="search" placeholder="Search Videos..."}}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" {{action "updateSearch"}}class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Component for my search bar

```
// app/components/search-bar.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  userSearch: "",
  actions: {
    updateSearch: function() {
      this.set("userSearch", this.get("search"));
      this.modelFor("videos").reload();
    }
  }
});
```

Video Route

```
// app/routes/video.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var userSearch = this.get("search") === undefined ? "Code" : this.get("search");
    this.set("search", userSearch);
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+ userSearch +"&maxResults=50&key="api key goes here";
    return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
      return data.items.filter(function(vid) {
        if(vid.id.videoId) {
          return vid;
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[reload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload) - will not call model hook method, in this case, you can send action to video route and try [refresh](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) from there.

EDIT:

Adjusting your code for your use case, Let me know if it's not working or anything wrong in this approach.

**app/routes/video.js**
Here we are using RSVP.hash function for returning [multiple model](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_multiple-models). I am including `userSearch` too. Its better to implement [query parameters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/query-params/) for this use case, but I implemented it without using it.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    userSearch: '',
    model: function() {
        var userSearch = this.get("userSearch") === undefined ? "Code" : this.get("userSearch");
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=" + userSearch + "&maxResults=50&key=apikey";
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            videosList: Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
                return data.items.filter(function(vid) {
                    if (vid.id.videoId) {
                        return vid;
                    }
                });
            }),
            userSearch: userSearch
        });
    },
    actions: {
        refreshRoute(userSearch) {
            this.set('userSearch',userSearch);
            this.refresh();
        },
    }
});
```

**app/controllers/viedo.js**
It contains refreshRoute function and this will call refreshRoute function available in video route file.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
      refreshRoute(userSearch){
          this.sendAction('refreshRoute',userSearch);
      }
  }
});
```

**app/templates/video.hbs**
1. I am passing `userSearch` property and `refreshRoute` action name to search-bar component
2. Accessing `videosList` using `model.videosList`

```
<div class="row">
  {{search-bar userSearch=model.userSearch refreshRoute="refreshRoute"}}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <hr>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      {{video-list model=model.videosList}}
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right video-container">
          {{#if  videoId}}
            <iframe id="video-player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoId}}"></iframe>
          {{else}}
            <iframe id="video-player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kEpOF7vUymc"></iframe>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/components/search-bar.js**
Here you will get `userSearch` property as external attributes ie. it will be passed as an argument on including the component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    userSearch:'',//external attributes
    actions: {
        updateSearch() {
            var userSearch = this.get('userSearch');
            this.sendAction('refreshRoute',userSearch); //this will call corresponding controller refreshRoute method
        }
    }
});
```

**app/templates/components/search-bar.hbs**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-4">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false">
        {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=userSearch id="search" placeholder="Search Videos..."}}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" {{action "updateSearch"}}class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that previously. The whole page would reload and the user input would be lost.

Comment: refresh will fire beforeModel, model, and afterModel hooks. then data will be updated.in templates. It looks your code is little confused with `search` and `userSearch` property that might be the reason for user input lose. You might need to introduce queryParam for search

Comment: My understanding is that I am taking the value from the input and setting that value to the userSearch property. Is my expectation correct or am I doing something different?

Comment: Yes you are right. so do you expect `userSearch` would be available in `routes/video.js` file ? I am not able to understand code `this.set("search", userSearch)`   in model hook

Comment: I was thinking that it would be available on the routes/video.js. It would see that a change had occured and then refresh the model to get new results from the api. I thought "search" would be global therefore it could be set within the model.

Comment: `search` is not global. it would be available if its declared in route then it would be available only in route. and if its declared in component then it would be available in component alone.

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean there is no way to break my search bar into it's own component?

Comment: This gives me the following error: "Nothing handled the action 'updateSearch'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble."

Comment: `updateSearch` function should be present in actions hash of the search-bar component. you can copy files content from my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132840/discussion-between-kumkanillam-and-dlf85).